# Visual Studio 2015 : how to get not updated file report

Tags: team-foundation-server, visual-studio

Moving from VisualStudio 2012 to VisualStudio 2015 i noticed that the option "Automatically GetLatest" is no more available.

So i'm tring to figure out the way on which i can get a report about which files are updated and which are not (like in Source Control Explorer but without the need of navigating the entire folder tree).

Comment: What is the question? The two paragraph are unrelated. I assume the Source Control provider is TFVC, but which TFS version are you using?

Comment: Sorry for my bad english.
I have read that starting from VS2015 there is no more support to the "Automatically GetLatest" when a solution is opened.
So i try to find a surrogate alternative, and i think that a report of old files (not updated) could help.
I'm using the version 15.117.26714.0